# The 2-norm of a positive circulant matrix

Tags: matrix-analysis, norms

Define a circulant matrix $A$ for complex numbers $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ as follows:

$$
\text{circ}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=
\left[ \begin{matrix}
a_1& a_2 & \cdots & a_{n-1} & a_n \\
a_n& a_1 & \cdots & a_{n-2} & a_{n-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\vdots\\
a_3& a_4 & \cdots & a_1 & a_2\\
a_2& a_3 & \cdots & a_{n} & a_1\\
\end{matrix} \right].
$$

In particular, assume $a_j \geq 0$ for $j = 1, ..., n$.  (Note: Initially I thought $n$ had to be odd, but this is not the case.)

> I conjecture that $$||A||_2 = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j.$$

My certainty is informed by a weird detour I went on in my research, and by looking at a bunch of random matrices in Matlab.  (See a code snippet below.)

I have an idea for the proof, but for easy reference, let me first establish a few properties of circulant matrices, taken from Philip J. Davis' book *Circulant Matrices*.

- Circulant matrices form a linear subspace in $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$.
- Define $ \Pi = \text{circ}(0,1,0,...,0) $.  Then $A$ is circulant if and only if $A\Pi = \Pi A$.
- $A$ is circulant if and only if $ A = a_1I + a_2\Pi + ... a_n\Pi^{n-1} $.
- Let $F$ denote the Fourier matrix of dimension $n$, i.e,
  $$
  F = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \begin{bmatrix}
  1&1&1&1&\cdots &1 \\
  1&\omega&\omega^2&\omega^3&\cdots&\omega^{n-1} \\
  1&\omega^2&\omega^4&\omega^6&\cdots&\omega^{2(n-1)}\\ 1&\omega^3&\omega^6&\omega^9&\cdots&\omega^{3(n-1)}\\
  \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
  1&\omega^{n-1}&\omega^{2(n-1)}&\omega^{3(n-1)}&\cdots&\omega^{(n-1)(n-1)}\\
  \end{bmatrix},
  $$
  for $ \omega = \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right) $.  Also, let $p(z)$ denote the *representative polynomial* of $A$, where
  $$
  p(z) = a_1 + a_2z + ... + a_n z^{n-1}.
  $$
  Then 
  $$
  A = F^* D F,
  $$
  where $ D = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, ... \lambda_n) $, and $\lambda_m = p(\omega^{m-1}) $.

Now, my proof idea:

**Proof of conjecture** (thus far):

$ ||A||^2_2 = ||F^* D F||^2_2. $  Since $F$ is unitary, $ ||A||^2_2 = ||D||^2_2. $

Now, 
$$
||D||^2_2 = \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n}p(\omega^{m-1})^2
$$
Let ${\alpha} = (\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$ denote a multi-index with $ |\alpha| = 2 $.  Define
$$
P^m_\alpha =
\begin{cases} 
2a_ia_j\omega^{(i+j-2)(m-1)} & \alpha_i = \alpha_j = 1, i \neq j \\
a_j^2\omega^{2(j-1)(m-1)} & \alpha_j = 2 
\end{cases}
$$
Then, by the multinomial theorem,
$$
||D||^2_2 = \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n} \sum\limits_{|\alpha|=2} P^m_\alpha.
$$
Switching the order of summation, we obtain that
$$
||D||^2_2 = \sum\limits_{\alpha_i = \alpha_j = 1, i \neq j} {2 a_i a_j \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n} \omega^{(i+j-2)(m-1)}} + \sum\limits_{\alpha_j = 2} {a_j^2 \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n} \omega^{2(j-1)(m-1)}}.
$$

> **Claim**: $$ \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n} \omega^{(i+j-2)(m-1)} = \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n} \omega^{2(j-1)(m-1)} = 1. $$

Then
$$
||D||^2_2 = (a_1 + ... + a_n)^2,
$$
leading to the desired result.

However, I am hung up on showing the claim, and after discussing the problem with a more algebraically aware colleague, I'm not even sure it's true.  And if I've made a mistake, I can't find it.

*Note: if my conjecture here is correct, then it would partially answer part of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167388/operator-norms-of-circulant-matrices).*

*Matlab code snippet*:

```
n = 11; P = zeros(n); P(2:end,1:end-1) = eye(n-1); P(1,end) = 1;
a = rand(n,1); abs(sum(a))
A = zeros(n); for i = 1:n; A = A + P^(i-1)*a(i); end; norm(A)
```

Comment: By the 2-norm, do you mean the operator norm of the matrix as an operator on Euclidean space? If so, then this norm is just the spectral radius of your matrix (circulants are normal) and in fact is equal, once you diagonalize A using the Fourier matrix, to the supremum over all $n$th roots of unity of the polynomial that corresponds to your matrix. Since the polynomial has positive entries, it is clear that the maximum is attained at $1$, proving your "conjecture"

Comment: On the other hand, if by the 2-norm you mean what I would call the Hilbert-Schmidt norm, then I am fairly sure your "conjecture" would be false

Comment: @YemonChoi I do mean the operator norm.  (Sorry, I thought I was using standard notation.)  And, thanks!  I can't believe I missed that detail.

Comment: That's fine: I think your notation _is_ standard among people doing matrix analysis; but less common in the worlds of Banach spaces and Banach algebras, which are where I originally learned my functional analysis.

Comment: What you ask here is basically the content of my [comment](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/167388/operator-norms-of-circulant-matrices#comment424035_167388) in the [other question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/167388/operator-norms-of-circulant-matrices) you linked to. The proof in my reference is essentially @YemonChoi's argument.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni They are related, yes. I had not read your comment until now.  If you feel that this question is too redundant, I'd be happy to take it down.  I had initially thought the proof would lead to some interesting exploration of roots of unity... but, alas, the simple proof wins.